# Determine Memory used by a Function in Python

Tags: python, memory, time

I was wondering if there is simple way to measure the memory used to execute a function similar to the way you can time a function.

For example, I can time a function and append the elapsed time to a list by doing the following:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

timePerTenRuns = []

# Loop through numRuns to generate an average
#
for i in range(0, len(numRuns)):

    # Generate random data
    #
    randList = getRand(k, randStart, k/randDivisor)

    # Time the function
    #
    start = timer()

    # Execute function to count duplicates in a random list
    #
    countDuplicates(randList)

    # Take the time at function's end
    #
    end = timer()

    # Append time for one execution of function
    #
    timePerTenRuns.append(end-start)
```

I would like to do the same to calculate and store the memory required to execute that function, then append it to a similar list.

I've read about tools such as memory_profiler, memory_usage, and others, but none have seemed to be able to produce the implementation I am looking for.

Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

Ryan